# Install V8JS on Mac Catalina

Tags: php, homebrew, pecl, macos-catalina, v8js

I've been trying to install php v8js on my Catalina for a week now. Can you help please? I tried all kind of command line steps. No luck.

**php -v**

```
PHP 7.4.0 (cli) (built: Nov 29 2019 16:18:44) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.0, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: https://github.com/phpv8/v8js/issues/380#issuecomment-502695765
if v8 7.4 version is enough for you

Comment: thanks. already tried that. didn't work either